# Why is event space 2 power of omega?

Tags: probability

For this example the event space F is defined as 2 to the power of omega :

[image]

Should the event space not be 6 as there are 6 possibilities ?

2 to the power of omega is 64, so event space is 64 but this event space is not utilized in the example ?

Comment: $2^{\Omega}$ denotes the set of all the subsets of $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$.

Comment: It is the power set. Set of every subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: Throwing a die, there are $6$ elementary or atomic events, namely the faces which can be shown. But these can be combined (e.g. with unions and complements) into $64$ possible events in the event space, such as the face shown being even.

Comment: @Henry The event space then throwing a die is 64 , but as there are just 6 possible outcomes, out of the event space 58 events are will never occur. So the event space defines all events of which some can never occur (Unless in the e.g of the die, we throw 6 die instead of 1) ?

Comment: No: the face showing being even can occur (with probability $\frac12$ for a fair die) and is an event.  The only element of the event space which has probability $0$ is equivalent to the die not showing a number from $1$ to $6$.

Comment: @Henry the event space does not include the P of being even or odd, it's just all combinations of {1,2,3,4,5,6} ?

Comment: The face showing being $2$ is an event $\{2\}$, the face showing being even is an event $\{2,4,6\}$, the face showing being prime is an event $\{2,3,5\}$, the face showing being $5$ or less is an event $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (and is the same event as the face showing not being $6$) , the face showing being $42$ or less is an event $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the face showing being $0$ or less is an event $\{\}=\emptyset$, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested in comments:

Throwing a die, there are $6$ elementary or atomic events, namely the faces which can be shown. But these can be combined (e.g. with unions and complements) into $64$ possible events in the event space, such as the face shown being even.

The face showing being $2$ is an event $\{2\}$, the face showing being even is an event  $\{2,4,6\}$, the face showing being prime is an event  $\{2,3,5\} $, the face showing being  $5$ or less is an event  $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ (and is the same event as the face showing not being  $6$), the face showing being  $42$ or less is an event  $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, the face showing being  $0$ or less is an event  $\{\}=\emptyset$, and so on

Answer (score 1):

$2^{\Omega}$ denotes the set of all the subsets of $\Omega = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 \}$.
For example $\{2, 4, 6 \} \in 2^{\Omega}$.